# Saving HTML 5 Canvas as Image on the server using ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, file-upload, html5-canvas, base64

I need some help here..

Im trying to save a canvas image after drawing..

following this example (http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1662-saving-html-5-canvas-as-image-on-the-server-using-aspnet.aspx)

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {

    var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
    image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../../Home/UploadImage?imageData=" + image,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('Image saved successfully !');
        }
    });
});
```

the controller:

```
public void UploadImage(string imageData)
{
    string fileNameWitPath = path + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(" ", "- ").Replace(":", "") + ".png";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

But when im trying to convert form base64 the string that is passed like parameter in method, throw an error

> Invalid length for a character array Base-64.

Comment: How long is image when appended to imageData?  If it is reasonably large (>1500 characters), then I would suspect your url is being chopped.  Try taking the value directly from the webpage via an alert or something and using it in a .NET program to determine if it works for the full image data length.  If this works, use content to send the data via post rather then url?param=data (still subject to 2,000 character limits here)

Comment: In addition to @PeterSmith's suggestion, since you're making a POST anyways, might as well put it in the POST data.

Comment: the imageData have 1400 characters.. i get the string in the controller but when im trying to convert from base 64 string (myString) throw a FormatException (Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.)

Comment: @Fausto How did you solve this problem? Did you use the contentType as suggested, because it doesn't worked for me

Comment: `contentType` should be `ContentType`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't post data with querystring parameters

Try this;

```
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {

        var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
        image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "../../Home/UploadImage",
            data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('Image saved successfully !');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I tryied sending data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }', but the imagData parameter in action method is null..

Comment: Try adding `alert(image);` to your javascript code. See if `image` is null

Comment: i send the imageData string in ajax like this:

url: "../../Home/UploadImage?imageData="+image,

and i receive the string, but when im trying to convert from base 64 string (myString) throw a FormatException ( Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.)

Comment: As @PeterSmith mentioned before, [querystring limit in IE is 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427/) characters. You've receiving that error cause your base64 image data gets cropped. You need to make POST request to your action.

Comment: y'all dun saved my life.

Comment: `contentType` should be `ContentType`.

Answer (score 3):

In that example, the author has posted the image data using a hidden field, notice below line of code in his article

```
<input type="hidden" name="imageData" id="imageData" />
```

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2665/saving-html-5-canvas-as-image-in-aspnet-mvc

And on click of the button, he is submitting the form after getting canvas data to the hidden field so follow the same approach. As written by Mehmet, querystring has limitations and its prone to be modified as it goes via url.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of this

```
image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
```

use this:

```
image = image.substr(23, image.length);
```

remove the leading characters up to the first comma (use any dev tool to see what you posted).