# How does ReadAsMultipartAsync actually work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I have a `canvas` element in a web site that I'm uploading using the FormData API. Here's how I do it:

```
upload: function (e) {
    var file = this.imagePreview.ui.canvas.get(0).toDataURL("image/jpeg")
                   .replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '');
    if (file) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        $.ajax({
            url: app.getApiRoot + 'UserFiles/',
            type: "post",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            error: function () {
                $("#file_upload_result").html('there was an error while submitting');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

where I'm replacing the whole `data:image/jpeg;base64,` business as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10792986/2112866).

On the backend I have the following multipart controller:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostUserFile()
{
    string imageDir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadedImageDir"];
    var PATH = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + imageDir);
    var rootUrl = Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath, String.Empty);

    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        var streamProvider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(PATH);
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }

            var files = streamProvider.FileData.Select(i =>
                        {
                            var info = new FileInfo(i.LocalFileName);
                            return new UserFile(User.Identity.GetUserId(), info.Name, rootUrl + "/" + imageDir + "/" + info.Name, info.Length / 1024);
                        });

            db.UserFiles.AddRange(files);
            db.SaveChangesAsync();
        });

        return Ok();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
    }
}
```

Where I implement a `CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider` as follows:

```
public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path)
        : base(path)
    { }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(Headers.HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        var name = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headers.ContentDisposition.FileName) ? 
                      headers.ContentDisposition.FileName : 
                      "NoName";
        // This is here because Chrome submits files in quotation 
        // marks which get treated as part of the filename and get escaped
        return name.Replace("\"\"", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Sadly, the `FileData` on the `streamProvider` fed into the `ReadAsMultipartAsync` method is empty:

[image: FileData count = 0]

And another thing I find interesting is that the uploaded binary file is escaped, as I notice from the watch window:

[image: Escaped data]

The `%2f` is the escape sequence for the `/` character.

***I simply can't*** pinpoint the problem. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Mixing ContinueWith and async/await leads to problems, just do `await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);` and everything in the `.ContinueWith` would just go after the await like normal code.

Or remove async/await and add:

```
return Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).Continu‌​eWith...
```

Also you can look this link: [Sending HTML Form Data in ASP.NET Web API: File Upload and Multipart MIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2)

Comment: Please, explain the answer with more detail.

Comment: Please, try to learn how to use Stackoverflow. Edit the answer, do not add information in the comments. Read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Sounds very reasonable. Let me implement it later today, and get back to you.