# Send canvas image to server and return processed image from server to client to display

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html, canvas

I am trying to upload canvas image from client to server and then after processing sending this processed image back to client to display it again on same canvas. I am able to upload the canvas Image by using Canvas DataURL. Here is the link thst I followed - 
[Saving HTML 5 Canvas as Image on the server using ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792986/saving-html-5-canvas-as-image-on-the-server-using-asp-net)

After uploading I saved the image and did some processing on it. Now how can I send this processed image back to client to display it again on canvas.

I am new to HTML5 and asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send the image back from the server to the client, you should use SignalR (or another framework/library which implements websockets). The other way is to request the image from the server, but you have to be sure that the webserver has finished processing the image.