# POST BASE64(from canvas toDataURL()) IMAGE WITH C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

(First of all, sorry for a bad english, i'm not so good) 
I have a canvas for creating memes, i want to save the created meme as a png iimage into a folder in my project and save the path into the database.
I have no idea how i have to do.
I'd like to use a web api because in the front end i use JavaScript for making the meme, and i can use the toDataURL() method that return a base64 not a png. 
Can you help me?

Comment: **yes, we can/might help you if your question is clearer.** What's your question, again? Please be more specific. You could also include your code and state where you have difficulties.

Comment: I have no code because simply i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Canvas for creating meme(a meme generator) , i have to save the meme created, and i must use the canvas method toDataURL() that return a base64 image, but i want a png image and want to save it into the server

Comment: have you tried searching for *how to save image to database*?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php

Comment: you can also try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792986/saving-html-5-canvas-as-image-on-the-server-using-asp-net

Comment: If this will not work?